# How to make all same ship labels on one page of labels?

Tags: microsoft-excel, label

Most label programs print ONE address per label, and all labels printed on a flat sheet of labels are different. I need the opposite. I need all labels printed on a page to be the same as they are ship labels which will be applied to many shipped boxes. You might envision this as printing return address labels which are all the same.

1. I have skills with Excel, MS Word, MS Access, and Perl. I'm not saying these tools are the best tools for the job, it's just what I have.
2. We have Office 2010, we cannot upgrade, though I might be able to sneak by and install LibreOffice if needed.
3. My sheet of labels has 4 labels across and 10 labels down. Each label is 51mm across and 28mm high. Left margin on sheet is 4mm.
4. While I'm in the US  I prefer to use mm.
5. The problem is each label has 4 different areas that are formatted differently with different sized fonts, and one area is a barcode.
6. The image below is what I did in Excel.
7. The barcode is vertically and horizontally centered to accommodate barcode standards for white space on all sides of the barcode.
8. I already did some searching on the net but my case seems to be very unusual.
9. I already tried to do this in Excel by repeating data in all cells but the upper left cells. I.e. all other cells just point to the upper left 4 cells.

[image: Label sample in Excel]

Anyone know how I can do this? Thanks!

Comment: Get the "avery" sheet number of your lable page and download that page setup from avery (or whoever makes your lable paper) for MS Word.  Then simply copy paste you lable data into each area on the lable sheet in MS Word.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Get the "avery" sheet number of your lable page and download that page setup from avery (or whoever makes your lable paper) for MS Word. Then simply copy paste you lable data into each area on the lable sheet in MS Word.